# same records can't insert in datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable "dt".Sometimes my records are repeated and i get this error:

> This row already belongs to this table.

I want to insert same records in my datatable .Because i need to show them to my user.

Here is my code :

```
public DataSet TitForTat()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("myt");
             dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("iteration", typeof(int)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("prison1", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("prison2", typeof (string)));
        prison[] prisons = new prison[2];
        prisons[0] = new prison();
        prisons[1] = new prison();
        //---------------------------
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        prisons[0]._state = "c";
        prisons[1]._state = valueOfState[rd.Next(0, 1)];
        dr["iteration"] = 0;
        dr["prison1"] = "c";
        dr["prison2"] = prisons[1]._state;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        //----------------------
        for (int i = 1; i <= _iteration; i++)
        {
            prisons[0]._state = prisons[1]._state;
            prisons[1]._state = valueOfState[rd.Next(0, 1)];
            DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
            dr["iteration"] =i;

            dr["prison1"] = prisons[0]._state;
            dr["prison2"] = prisons[1]._state;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        return ds;
    }
```

Comment: This is what happens when you use poorly named variables. You should be adding `dr1` not `dr`, try being more descriptive in future and you should find these problems disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss `dr1` with `dr`:

Change this

```
 dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

To this

```
 dt.Rows.Add(dr1);
```

in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is raised if you try to add a `DataRow` to a table that already belongs to this or another `DataTable`. You have to copy the values or use [`ImportRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.importrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    // ...
    // dt.Rows.Add(dr);  // no
    dt.ImportRow(dr);    // yes
    // works also, copies the fields to a new row:
    // DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);  
}
```